# Comparing instances of UITableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to iOS, swift. To compare instances of classes in swift we have to conform Equatable protocol and add == method. But when we use two tableviews in UIViewController we compare tableviews using == in delegate methods.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
  if tableView == mTableViewOne
   {

   }
  else if tableView == mTableViewTwo
   {

   }
}
```

I checked UITableView Documentation but it does not conform to equatable protocol. How should I compare UITableViews?

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare? Do you want to compare content of tableviews?

Comment: mTableViewOne and mTableViewTwo are 'probably' IBOutlets and the comparision is testing the two IBOutlet references for equality. Which is a valid test.

Comment: My question is how am i able to compare instances with == without conforming Equatable protocol

Comment: Two tableview instances can be compared using equatable protocol. What's the problem which you are facing. When I tried I could easily compare between two tableview instances.

Comment: @Damo yes they are IBOutlets. Can you explain little bit more? They are objects right. How can they be compared??

Comment: @Priyal UITableView does not conform to Equatable protocol..How am i getting correct result even when they don't conform to Equatable protocol. That's my question

Comment: assign diferent tag to your tablevies and compare with it - tableView.tag == mTableViewOne.tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All UIKit classes are derived from NSObject(indirectly) and `NSObject` is conforming to the `Equatable` protocol. So, you can compare two UITableView references using the `==` operator.

**UITableView -> UIScrollView -> UIView -> UIResponder -> NSObject(Conforms to Equatable protocol)**

Comment: Yeah this is correct. NSObject conforms to Equatable and UITableView indirectly is a subclass of NSObject

Comment: @sahil, what about `===` operator?

Comment: @Karthick === (Identical to) operator  refer to exactly the same class instance. and == (Equal to) means that two instances are considered “equal” or “equivalent” in value.

Comment: @Sahil okay. Thanks bro.